# How to generate date for MySQL DATETIME type with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I need to get the records which are inserted in last 24 hours. I have read about it and got that I need to use `DATETIME` type in my MySQL date column.
 But my problem is I don't know how to generate date for MySQL  `DATETIME` type with PHP ? 
How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given your mention of a DATETIME type, it's important to note that MySQL stores nothing but a string in a special format. So you create a PHP string in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss and you're good to go. And yes, I realize the question is years old but I assume future readers will get here with a search term that includes "DATETIME type" and find this information useful.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Simply

```
$mysql_date_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Because **`DATETIME`** in mysql is **`YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss`**

Answer (score 15):

If you are looking just for a way to generate the datetime to insert into the datetime field just use the following code

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
```

or for the direct sql

```
INSERT INTO {TABLE} ({DATETIME}) VALUES (NOW())
```

This will create a date that looks like

```
2012-02-28 16:44:25
```

If you are looking for the query to get the last 24 hours use

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE date_field > NOW() - interval 1 day
```

Comment: I just want to add this in here - I believe if you use the `sql now()` function it will create the time depending on where the server is, not where you are. 

If the server is in another country or region with a different timezone it will use the timezone where the server is located instead of your own.

Comment: James111: it depends on what your timezone is of the server.  If your server timezone can be set to your current location, then it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go:

1. Use a textual representation - something like:

   ```
   <?php
       $year=2012; $month=2; $day=27;
       $hour=22; $minute=44; $second=58;

       $sql="SELECT something FROM something WHERE datecolumn>='$year-$month-$day $hour:$minute:$second'";
   ?>
   ```
2. Do this directly in SQL

   ```
   SELECT something FROM something WHERE datecolumn >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
   ```

Comment: I Don't know why the editor insists of numbering this 1. and 1., should be 1. and 2.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the MySQL database to do half the work, unless you do not like the time on the server.
Name: dateSomething
Type: TIMESTAMP
Default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

And then the SQL code

```
INSERT INTO {TABLE} ({dateSomething}) VALUES (DEFAULT)
```